# Mac OS X lid open/close event log

Tags: macos, event-log

Simple request really, I would like to record whenever the lid of my MacBook Pro has been opened or closed. Preferably a free app, but a minimally priced one would be fine too. A nice to have would be if I could choose more events like system startup or shutdown to log, but the important events to me are lid open and close.

Answer (score 1):

Check `SleepWatcher 2.2` from http://www.bernhard-baehr.de
It has sources.